# Restrict a library from going into final image

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am building a Yocto image. There are some GPLv3 libraries which are required only at build time. I have put GPLv3 as INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE and whitelisted the libraries which are required at build time. But these libraries are getting into the final image. How can I restrict them into the final image and only use them at the build time?

Comment: Can you post the library names examples, recipes example ?

Comment: Let's suppose the library is gdb, I want it during the build but not to go into the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PACKAGE_EXCLUDE worked for me. If packages listed under PACKAGE_EXCLUDE is getting into the final image, then this will raise an error.
Also if any other package has a runtime dependency on a package listed under PACKAGE_EXCLUDE, then this will raise an error too.

References:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-PACKAGE_EXCLUDE
https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/conf/documentation.conf#n313

Answer (score 1):

If we think about the Yocto basics, we know that everything goes into the final image is a collection of recipes providing packages that are collected together in a single root file system.

So, what makes a recipe goes into the final rootfs ?

- Added via `IMAGE_INSTALL`.
- Be set as `RDEPENDS` of another recipe.

You need to analyse that deeply to find out what goes into your final rootfs.

Also, you may not find it obvious in the content of `IMAGE_INSTALL` by running:

```bash
bitbake -e <your_image_recipe> | grep ^IMAGE_INSTALL=
```

but, you may see some `packagegroups` that are shipped. A packagegroup is a group that `RDEPENDS` on a list of other recipes.

So, you need to carefully analyse them (if found) to see what provides the lib you want to inhibit from rootfs.

`packagegroups` usually gets shipped dynamically via `IMAGE_FEATURES` variable.

So, those are the most important points that are responsible of shipping a recipe to the rootfs. So, Analyse your wanted recipe.

- Is it an `RDEPENDS` of another recipe ?
- Find out where exactly it gets called to be shipped.

Comment: This solution might work but I was looking for a variable based solution where I just need to list down the such packages.

Comment: If you give a specific example maybe I can understand more, because your question is too generic .

Comment: I have put GPLv3 license as INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE. The packages which are required in build, I have put in WHITELIST_GPL-3.0. But I only want these packages during build, I do not want them to go into the image.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the installation of lib from do_install task by adding something like this in recipe e.g gdb as you said

> do_install:append() 
> { 
> #remove the lib which you don't want to ship into image 
> }

And make sure the same lib is not added to FILES var in recipe

> e.g FILES:${PN} += "< lib >"